# Not able to get output html page from flask

Tags: html, flask, google-colaboratory, werkzeug

I am working in a simple flask project in colab. The whole program runs, and the run method produces a localhost URL. But I am not able to view the HTML site. It runs locally on my computer, but not in colab.

The error is displayed below:
[image: ERROR IMAGE]

I have changed my flask run method's host to 0.0.0.0 based on the following StackOverflow answer. [My previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61484769/9876569).

The whole code is available at [Code link.](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-pxyiIb1jROCKBd0C6SiwqO25hFBZHX8#scrollTo=rXKOIbdXTtFR)

Answer (score 1):

Run this code.

```
from google.colab.output import eval_js
eval_js("google.colab.kernel.proxyPort(5000)")
```

And use the printed URL instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: exactly where should i place eval_js function?

Comment: put it anywhere. Just copy the result URL, and open another tab.